# Binding Java application to MySQL in Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, mysql, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to bind MySQL service, which is in on prem cloud foundry, to my Java application. could anyone suggest me what are the necessary changes to be made in my code to access MySQL database.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot, this should happen *almost* automatically as [described in a Spring blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/27/binding-to-data-services-with-spring-boot-in-cloud-foundry).

If you are using Spring *without* Spring Boot, you may want to use [Spring Cloud Connectors](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector.html).

If you are using neither, you can interrogate the [VCAP_SERVICES environment variable](https://docs.run.pivotal.io/devguide/deploy-apps/environment-variable.html#VCAP-SERVICES) for details of your service.

Answer (score 0):

On cloud foundry, you will have to provision a service for your app.

Look for available services.

> cf marketplace

Identify the mysql service and the plan. Create the service instance

> cf create-service p-mysql 512mb mysql

To see the service instances

> cf services

Bind the service instance to your app

> cf bind-service myapp mysql

You can see the details as

> cf env myapp

`EngineerBetter` has already provided you articles on how to use Spring to leverage the service in your app code.

Here's a good quick reference for [CF CLI](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjpj66uwZ7QAhVpqVQKHQ1WBNgQFggbMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fs3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com%2Fecsteam-cloudfoundry%2FCloud%2BFoundry-CLI-Quick-Ref-ECSTeam.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHCOY9lt4WA0sT2mqVAEFs0GFoyag&sig2=tLzWeKCwuz2HLGaBCTY6iA&bvm=bv.138169073,d.cGw)